# Multiple document types with same mapping in Elasticseach

Tags: elasticsearch

I have index named `test` which can be associated to `n` number of documents types named `sub_test_1` to `sub_text_n`. But all will have same mapping.

Is there any way to make an index such all document types have same mapping for their documents? I.e. `test\sub_text1\_mapping` should be same as `test\sub_text2\_mapping`.

Otherwise if I have like `1000` document types, I will we having 1000 mappings of the same type referring to each document types.

UPDATE:

```
PUT /test_index/
{
  "settings": {
    "index.store.type": "default",
    "index": {
        "number_of_shards": 5,
        "number_of_replicas": 1,
        "refresh_interval": "60s"
    },
    "analysis": {
        "filter": {
            "porter_stemmer_en_EN": {
                "type": "stemmer",
                "name": "porter"
            },
            "default_stop_name_en_EN": {
                "type": "stop",
                "name": "_english_"
            },
            "snowball_stop_words_en_EN": {
                "type": "stop",
                "stopwords_path": "snowball.stop"
            },
            "smart_stop_words_en_EN": {
                "type": "stop",
                "stopwords_path": "smart.stop"
            },
            "shingle_filter_en_EN": {
                "type": "shingle",
                "min_shingle_size": "2",
                "max_shingle_size": "2",
                "output_unigrams": true
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Intended mapping:

```
{
  "sub_text" : {
    "properties" : {
      "_id" : {
        "include_in_all" : false,
        "type" : "string",
        "store" : true,
        "index" : "not_analyzed"
      },
      "alternate_id" : {
        "include_in_all" : false,
        "type" : "string",
        "store" : true,
        "index" : "not_analyzed"
      },
      "text" : {
        "type" : "multi_field",
        "fields" : {
          "text" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "store" : true,
            "index" : "analyzed",
          },
          "pdf": {
            "type" : "attachment",
            "fields" : {
                "pdf" : {
                    "type" : "string",
                    "store" : true,
                    "index" : "analyzed",
                }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want this mapping to be an individual mapping for all `sub_text`s I create so that I can change it for one `sub_text` without affecting others e.g. I may want to add two custom analyzers to `sub_text1` and three analyzers to `sub_text3`, rest others will stay same.

UPDATE:

```
PUT /my-index/document_set/_mapping
{
  "properties": {
    "type": {
      "type": "string",
      "index": "not_analyzed"
    },
    "doc_id": {
      "type": "string",
      "index": "not_analyzed"
    },
    "plain_text": {
      "type": "string",
      "store": true,
      "index": "analyzed"
    },
    "pdf_text": {
      "type": "attachment",
      "fields": {
        "pdf_text": {
          "type": "string",
          "store": true,
          "index": "analyzed"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

POST /my-index/document_set/1
{
  "type": "d1",
  "doc_id": "1",
  "plain_text": "simple text for doc1."
}

POST /my-index/document_set/2
{
  "type": "d1",
  "doc_id": "2",
  "pdf_text": "cGRmIHRleHQgaXMgaGVyZS4="
}

POST /my-index/document_set/3
{
  "type": "d2",
  "doc_id": "3",
  "plain_text": "simple text for doc3 in d2."
}

POST /my-index/document_set/4
{
  "type": "d2",
  "doc_id": "4",
  "pdf_text": "cGRmIHRleHQgaXMgaGVyZSBpbiBkMi4="
}

GET /my-index/document_set/_search
{
  "query" : {
    "filtered" : {
      "filter" : {
        "term" : {
          "type" : "d1"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This gives me the documents related to type "d1". How to add analyzers only to document of type "d1"?

Answer (score 1):

At the moment a possible solution is to use [index templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/indices-templates.html) or [dynamic mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/mapping-dynamic-mapping.html). However they do not allow wildcard type matching so you would have to use the `_default_` root type to apply the mappings to all types in the index and thus it would be up to you to ensure that all your types can be applied to the same dynamic mapping. This template example may work for you:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/_template/template_1 -d '
{
    "template" : "test",
    "mappings" : {
        "_default_" : {
            "dynamic": true,
            "properties": {
                "field1": {
                   "type": "string",
                   "index": "not_analyzed"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
'
```

Comment: Thnks for the suggestion. Is the `parent-child` mapping useful for my use case? Like if I make `sub_text1`, parent of the documents that I will index.

Comment: Unfortunately your update to the question has signficantly altered the solution. In this latter case you may like to use `_default_` dynamic template mappings (as linked in the answer) where the field mappings will be applied to all fields that your documents may have.

Answer (score 0):

Do not do this.

> Otherwise if I have like 1000 document types, I will we having 1000 mappings of the same type referring to each document types.

You're exactly right. For every additional `_type` *with an identical mapping* you are needlessly adding to the size of your index's mapping. They will not be merged, nor will any compression save you.

A much better solution is to simply create a shared `_type` and to create a field that represents the intended type. This completely avoids having wasted mappings and all of the negatives associated with it, including an unnecessary increase for your cluster state's size.

From there, you can imitate what Elasticsearch is doing for you and filter on *your* custom type without ballooning your mappings.

```
$ curl -XPUT localhost:9200/my-index -d '{
  "mappings" : {
    "my-type" : {
      "properties" : {
        "type" : {
          "type" : "string",
          "index" : "not_analyzed"
        },
        # ... whatever other mappings exist ...
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Then, for any search against `sub_text1` (etc.), then you can do a `term` (for one) or `terms` (for more than one) filter to imitate the `_type` filter that would happen for you.

```
$ curl -XGET localhost:9200/my-index/my-type/_search -d '{
  "query" : {
    "filtered" : {
      "filter" : {
        "term" : {
          "type" : "sub_text1"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

This is doing the same thing as the `_type` filter and you can create `_alias`es that contain the filter *if* you want to have the higher level search capability without exposing client-level logic to the filtering.

Comment: That's really a different question entirely. Regardless, my answer stays the same: don't do it. You do **not** want to have the same field mapped in different ways within the same index (regardless of types) because it will **not** work. If you have `field1` mapped with one analyzer in `index1/typeA` and `field1` mapped with a different analyzer in `index1/typeB`, then you it will not work. Relatedly, you're inherently saying that they're not the same mappings.

Comment: I have made an update to the question where I used to your suggestion in my use-case. See if you can help me out.

Comment: If you only want to add analyzers to d1, then you would simply not have them as part of it. If they're semantically different things, then you either want to use parent/child relationships, where you _must_ use multiple types and it is therefore an acceptable exception to the rule, or you should use multiple indices and separate the documents altogether. _There's no reason to share an index if the content is not meant to be queried together_.

Comment: Is it right to have ~1000 indices or even more? I had designed a parent-child relationship for this problem. I asked about that here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31363587/updating-childs-mappings-in-a-parent-child-mapping-in-elasticsearch or should I use aliases and routing on every document set type?